# Terraform - Azure how to get deployment webhook URL

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Using [hashicorp/azurerm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs) provider I want to set up a [webhook](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/container_registry_webhook) that would trigger a deployment.

I have a web app that loads the newest Docker image on restart. However, **I need a `scmUri`** of the resource to setup the webhook:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "web" {
  app_settings = {
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL      = url
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.acr-service-principal-id.value
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.acr-service-principal-password.value
    ...
  }
  ...
}

resource "azurerm_container_registry_webhook" "webhook" {
  service_uri = "<scm URL of the azurerm_linux_web_app.web>/docker/hook"
  ...
}
```

I have found a way to query the `scmUri` using various other languages... but nothing using the `azurepm` provider:

- REST: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/list-publishing-credentials
- Bicep: https://github.com/Azure/bicep/discussions/3352#discussioncomment-976818
- [Pulumi: Add Azure Web App Service web hook to Azure Container Registry for continuous deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64557665/pulumi-add-azure-web-app-service-web-hook-to-azure-container-registry-for-conti/64567900#64567900)

After everything is deployed I can also copy the `scmUri` manually from Azure, but I would prefer a fully automated setup:

[image: Deployment Center]

Comment: I've now also found an option to define the `scmUri` as: `https://${azurerm_linux_web_app.web.site_credential.0.username}:${azurerm_linux_web_app.web.site_credential.0.password}@${azurerm_linux_web_app.web.name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/docker/hook`

Comment: You should probably write this as an answer as it looks like the only solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.28.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source  = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "1.2.0"
    }
  }
}

...

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "web" {
  name                = "my-webapp"
  app_settings = {
    DOCKER_ENABLE_CI = "true"
    DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL : "*****"
    WEBSITES_PORT : "8080"
  }
  ... # other settings
}


resource "azurerm_container_registry_webhook" "webhook" {
  service_uri         = "https://${azurerm_linux_web_app.web.site_credential.0.name}:${azurerm_linux_web_app.web.site_credential.0.password}@${azurerm_linux_web_app.web.name}.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/registry/webhook"
  location            = "*****"
  registry_name       = "*****"
  name                = "${replace(azurerm_linux_web_app.web.name, "/-|_|\\W/", "")}hook" # only alphanumeric characters allowed
  actions             = ["push"]
  resource_group_name = "*****"
}
```

The `service_uri` is a bit different than the URL in the comment under the question (so make sure to check how your webhook URL looks in the web application's deployment center section) and I had to use `.web.site_credential.0.name` instead of `.web.site_credential.0.username` to access the correct attribute.